# NodeJS: remove html from text but leave the alt of images

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, emoji

I have HTML text as string, with emoji as image tag like this:

```
const htmlText = '<p>test emoji <span title="Smile" class="animated-emoticon-20-smile"><img title="Smile" alt=""></span> and more <span title="Emo" class="animated-emoticon-20-emo"><img title="Emo" alt=""></span><span title="Star eyes" class="animated-emoticon-20-stareyes"><img title="Star eyes" alt=""></span></p>'
```

How can I convert it to the source text without the HTML tags but with the emoji?

I try this:

`htmlText.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '')`

=> `'test emoji  and more '`

But I want also the emoji to be displayed, as in the alt of the image, like this:

`test emoji  and more`

maybe the regex has to be different.

Comment: It is error prone to parse html with a regex. Is the html always structured like this or can the format also be completely different? Did you consider using a dom parser instead?

Comment: It should be always structured like this

Comment: Whatever you're doing with emojis there, I bet it really screws up accessibility.

Comment: what is the alternative? I'm getting this message from MS Teams Bot when a user type message with emoji

Comment: Oh. Teams. Then it's probably not something you have to worry about about. I'd thought you were working with a normal web site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines?

```
htmlText.replace(/(?:<|(?<=\p{EPres}))[^>\p{EPres}]+(?:>|(?=\p{EPres}))/gu, "")
```

`\p{EPres}` is the escape sequence for the [binary unicode property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-binary-unicode-properties) Emoji_Presentation (which is true for emojis). The regex must have the `u` flag for it to be recognised as such.

Basically you are matching all characters except > and emojis, starting either from the first < or the character after the first emoji, and up to either the first > or the character before the first emoji.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting - `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression`. Maybe my nodejs version doen't support EPres ?

Comment: (Sorry for the late response.) This is incredibly annoying... It is the missing opening bracket, it should be /(?:<|(?<=\p{EPres}))[^>\p{EPres}]+(?:>|(?=\p{EPres}))/gu. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const htmlText = '<p>test emoji <span title="Smile" class="animated-emoticon-20-smile"><img title="Smile" alt=""></span> and more <span title="Emo" class="animated-emoticon-20-emo"><img title="Emo" alt=""></span><span title="Star eyes" class="animated-emoticon-20-stareyes"><img title="Star eyes" alt=""></span></p>'
console.log(htmlText.replace(/<(?:[^<>]*?\salt="([^"]*)")?[^<>]*>/g, '$1') )
```

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group:

  - `[^<>]*?` - zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` as few as
    possible
  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `alt="` - a fixed string
  - `([^"]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"` char
- `)` - end of the group, repeat 1 or 0 times
- `[^<>]*` - zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` as many as possible
- `>` - a `>` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KT70g/2).